# Problems in printing from HP 3516 Wireless

Tags: wireless, printing, hp

I'm having problems to set my HP 3516 Deksjet Ink (scan+printer+copy). I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

Going to Printers>Add, it is possible to identify the printer, set the drive option. In the end, when I ask to print the test page, it keeps connecting to printer and nothing happen. No error message, neither status modification.

I have also tried to connect the printer by HPLIP using the USB cable. Nothing happen either.

On my wife windows, the printer runs ok!

I have already investigated around the Internet, but nothing helped me. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open "Printers" at the system dropdown menu, right click the icon that corresponds to your HP Deskjet Ink Advantage 3516 printer, select "properties", at the "Manufacturer and Model" box click at the "Change" button, let it search for the printer driver, when the manufacturers list shows up, select "HP", when the models list shows up, select the following model:

Deskjet Ink Adv 2010 k010, hpcups 3.12.2

Confirm the selection and finish the configurations, allowing to copy the fresh PPD (losing your previous configurations).

This will work properly.

Regards.

Comment: adding pics could explain more about what you are trying to say :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the hplip-gui? It is absolutely great, especially for hp printers. The package is available on the standard repos and is one apt-get install away.